# What is an efficient way to replace all values of a matrix except for those in rows or columns which contain a specific value?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to replace all values of the input matrix `X` with `np.nan` except for the rows and columns which contain a value `v`:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray 


def get_masked_array(X: NDArray[float], v: float) -> NDArray[float]:
     # something
     return arr
    

# Input float array
X = np.array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.],
              [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.],
              [ 5.,  5.,  6.,  6.,  6.],
              [ 7.,  8.,  9.,  9.,  9.],
              [10., 10., 10., 10., 10.]])
```

Expected results:

```
>>> get_masked_array(X, 2.)
array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.],
       [nan,  5.,  6., nan, nan],
       [nan,  8.,  9., nan, nan],
       [nan, 10., 10., nan, nan]])

>>> get_masked_array(X, 3.)
array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.],
       [nan, nan, nan,  4.,  4.],
       [nan, nan, nan,  6.,  6.],
       [nan, nan, nan,  9.,  9.],
       [nan, nan, nan, 10., 10.]])
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert values to nan which aren't in a row or column with the value `v`?

Comment: @ddejohn Sorry for the confusing question. Yes, I would like to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check row and column condition first and then combine them into a boolean condition taking advantage of [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
v = 2

eq_v = X == v
has_v = eq_v.any(0) | eq_v.any(1, keepdims=True)  # check if row or col has v
np.where(has_v, X, np.nan)

array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.],
       [nan,  5.,  6., nan, nan],
       [nan,  8.,  9., nan, nan],
       [nan, 10., 10., nan, nan]])
```

Using [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) (>= python 3.8), you can do this in one line as efficiently:

```
np.where((eq_v := (X == v)).any(0) | eq_v.any(1, keepdims=True), X, np.nan)
array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.],
       [nan,  5.,  6., nan, nan],
       [nan,  8.,  9., nan, nan],
       [nan, 10., 10., nan, nan]])
```

Comment: Nice use of the walrus operator

Comment: Ah, `keepdims`. I fiddled with this approach but wasn't aware of that kwarg. Nice solution.

Comment: @ddejohn yeah, that parameter tends to be left out. You had a great solution too. Upvoted ^

Answer (score 2):

This'll work but I'm sure there's an easier way:

```py
v = 2
rows, cols = map(np.unique, np.argwhere(X == v).T)
N = np.empty(X.shape, float)
N[:] = np.nan
N[rows, :] = X[rows, :]
N[:, cols] = X[:, cols]
```

Output:

```py
array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.],
       [nan,  5.,  6., nan, nan],
       [nan,  8.,  9., nan, nan],
       [nan, 10., 10., nan, nan]])
```

For `v = 3`:

```py
array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.],
       [nan, nan, nan,  4.,  4.],
       [nan, nan, nan,  6.,  6.],
       [nan, nan, nan,  9.,  9.],
       [nan, nan, nan, 10., 10.]])
```